# How to submit a form to server and get csv file from server via the internet wtih python?

Tags: python, asp.net, csv, post, web-scraping

I need to submit a form to the server and get csv file from the server via the internet with python.

The server website is (http://
222.158.245.253/obweb/data/c1/c1_output6.aspx?LocationNo=012), which publishes the observation data of sea in Japan.

So far, I always select the item and the date and click the button.
Then, When a file save dialog box is displayed, I preserve the csv file from the server.

I would like to automate these manual labors with python.
I have studied about python and web scraping and have used python modules(like BeautifulSoup).
However, This website is difficult to do web scraping due to aspx.

So, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid scraping if you can find out what URL the form is POSTing to. Inspect the source code of the page and see if the form tag has an action attribute. This is the URL that the form sends all of your fields to (including the item and date you specify).

You're going to want to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) library to make your POST request. It'll be something like this example from the requests quickstart:

```
payload = {'item': '<your item>', 'date': '<your date>'}
r = requests.post("<form post url>", data=payload)
```

You can then likely access the csv file that's returned with

```
print r.content
```

Though you may have to process r.content for it to be meaningful.